Angular Jasmine tests that continue upon previous tests
I have a service called items here is the spec file:
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ItemsService } from './items.service';

describe('ItemsListService', () => {
  let service: ItemsService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(ItemsService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should insert new item', () => {
    const item = {
      id: '123',
      name: 'item',
      baseUnit: 'unit',
      brand: 'brand',
      price: 100,
      quantity: 10,
      supplier: 'supplier',
      cost: 50,
      imageUrl: 'url',
    };
    service.insertItem(item);
    const items = service.getItems();
    expect(items.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    expect(items).toContain(item);
  });
});

And here is another service called orders that depends on items service to create orders from items stored.
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { OrdersService } from './orders.service';

describe('OrdersService', () => {
  let service: OrdersService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(OrdersService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should insert new order', async () => {
    const newOrder = await service.insertOrder(itemsService.getItems()[0]);
  });
});

So in order for orders service to create a new order it needs to access the item stored inside items service here service.insertOrder(itemsService.getItems()[0]).
How do I access the same instance of items service created in the spec file?

You want to reuse the same instance of ItemsService, which already has items added from the ItemsService Spec, in your OrdersService Spec without adding items again in the OrdersService Spec.
To achieve this, you need to ensure that the ItemsService in your OrdersService Spec reflects the state of the ItemsService from ItemsService Spec file(where items have been already added).
Since TestBed creates a fresh instance of the service for each spec by default, you can't directly share the instance across difference spec files unless you merge the setup in the same test suite run the tests sequentially.
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { OrdersService } from './orders.service.ts';
import { ItemsService } from './items.service.ts';

let ordersService: OrdersService;
let itemsService: ItemsService;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [OrdersService, ItemsService]
  })

  ordersService = TestBed.inject(OrdersService);
  itemsService = TestBed.inject(ItemsService);

  const item = {...your object...}

  itemsService.insertItem(item);
})

it('should insert new order using existing item from ItemsService', async () => {
  const newOrder = await ordersService.insertOrder(itemsService.getItems()[0])
  -- rest of your test case code --
}) 
})


This is not what I'm looking for. Don't want to merge two spec files into one.

Another option would be to share the state between your spec files, but that would involve storing the ItemsService instance globally, which is more complex and not typically recommended.
The best practice is to keep the tests for each service separate while ensuring they share the same instance when needed (like in Option 1). This method keeps the tests clean and focused on the specific service behavior while avoiding side effects between tests.
